# Generate a truly random text string with PHP?

Tags: passwords, php, random

How can I generate a truly cryptographically secure random text string in PHP (to be used as password)?

Allowed: a-z, A-Z, 0-9
Blocked: **Everything else**

Comment: Welcome to Information Security SE. Can you the reference the URL you used? Could you clarify the part of the question where you mention the list of characters that are / aren't allowed? Also, as this is a PHP-specific question it's more relevant on StackOverflow, though it seems like a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers aren't very good at generating "true" randomness - PHP alone will not give you that. But you can get something that is unpredictable enough to be used for password generation.

Use [`int random_int ( int $min , int $max )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php). It will use a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

How to go from being able to generate random integers in a certain interval to generating a random password is a programming question, and not a security question. So I will only shortly suggest that you make an string of all allowed characters, and have a for loop that picks a random letter from that string at a time.

Comment: This recommendation regarding picking a random letter from an array of allowable characters is equivalent to "Base-X" encoding. Base-36 and Base-64 encodings are fairly well-accepted methods of encoding more complex binary data in a string of typeable, printable characters.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that in computer science talking about "truly random text string" isnt just that easy.

Some stuff I would do is to use the [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function and set the 26 letters as 0-25 and the 10 numbers as 26-35. So if you rand(0,35), if you get the 3 you have a d to your password, same if you want to get uppercase letters, you include them to the rand() function.

Note this is for getting pseudorandom elements, so if you have each one of the elements as "pseudorandom", and you have enough big passwords made this way, its impossible with the computing capacity that we have today, that some computer could get your password.

I think this is the quicker way to sort this out.

Comment: `rand` is not the right tool for the task. Read the warning statement on the link you posted.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean something like this?

```
<?php

$alphabet = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
$random = array_rand($alphabet, 10); #set the length
foreach ($random as $letter) { echo $alphabet[$letter]; }

?>
```

Comment: I don't think that `array_rand` is cryptographically secure, so it should not be used for generating passwords. According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) it uses a Mersenne twister at best.

Comment: Well, there is no mentioning of cryptography in OP. Just about generating a random text string, which is what the above code does. But I do agree with you regarding new age `array_rand` function.

Comment: The name is a bit misleading I guess - your random numbers needs to be "cryptographically secure" even if your not doing crypto. OP mentions passwords, and those should *always* be generated using a cryptographically secure PRNG.